# Sdr set frequency C#

Tags: c#, sockets, software-defined-radio

In my sdr client Application in C# I am unable to properly convert frequency(10087000) in hexa decimal and pass it to socket.

I am using cloudIQ device and need help to set the frequency and other parameters using socket.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the frequency is in Int32

```
public String FrequencyToHexadecimal(Int32 frequency)
{
    Int32 networkOrder = IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(frequency);
    Byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(networkOrder);
    return BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-","");
}
```

The result will be a hexadecimal string in network byte order.